# i got error while creating a android project in eclipse 3.6.1

Tags: android, eclipse

I got the following error on error log,

```
"conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1"
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I had the same error after including (by mistake) android.jar into build path as a regular library. Is it not the case here?

Comment: Its happening while im adding the LWUIT library on android application... Now i resolved the issue.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Quote from http://d.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html:

> **Caution:** There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice.

Comment: I used LWUIT framework for my application. I got this issue while using this framework. But without using this framework i didn't face any issues like this.

Comment: I had the same issue, downgraded to 3.5.2 and its OK. Failing that, try the new IDEA X from IntelliJ, there is an EAP on the community edition which has android support

Comment: I used 3.5.2 also but problem still the same.

Comment: I used 3.5 also but problem still the same. how to resolve this issue.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I find that typically when I get this error, it can be easily resolved by cleaning the project and rebuilding (Project->Clean).